# Xamarin forms:Listview grouping issue

Tags: xamarin.forms, listviewgroup

I am trying to implement listview grouping for my following JSON data.

JSON Sample:

```
{ 
   "cbrainBibleBooksHB":[ { 
        "book":"2 John",
         "cbrainBibleTOList":[ 
            { 
               "bookName":"2 John",
               "chapter":"1",
               "pageUrl":"/edu-bible/9005/1/2-john-1"
            },
            {....}
         ]
      },
      { 
         "book":"3 John",
         "cbrainBibleTOList":[ 
            {  
               "bookName":"3 John",
               "chapter":"1",
               "pageUrl":"/edu-bible/9007/1/3-john-1"
            },
            {...}
         ]
      }
   ]
 }
```

I am trying to group the JSON data by its book name.

I tried like below:

**Model:**

```
public class BibleTestament
    {
        public List<CbrainBibleBooksHB> cbrainBibleBooksHB { get; set; }
    }

    public class CbrainBibleBooksHB : ObservableCollection<CbrainBibleTOList>
    {
        public string book { get; set; }
        public List<CbrainBibleTOList> cbrainBibleTOList { get; set; }
    }

    public class CbrainBibleTOList
    {
        public string chapter { get; set; }
        public string pageUrl { get; set; }
        public string bookName { get; set; }
    }
```

**Viewmodel**

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                var Response = await client.GetAsync("rest api");
                if (Response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string response = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Debug.WriteLine("response:>>" + response);
                    BibleTestament bibleTestament = new BibleTestament();
                    if (response != "")
                    {
                        bibleTestament = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BibleTestament>(response.ToString());
                    }
                    AllItems = new ObservableCollection<CbrainBibleBooksHB>(bibleTestament.cbrainBibleBooksHB);
```

**XAML**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView 
                HasUnevenRows="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems,Mode=TwoWay}"
                IsGroupingEnabled="True">
                <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Label 
                                Text="{Binding book}"
                                Font="Bold,20" 
                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                Margin="3"
                                TextColor="Black"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <StackLayout
                                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal">

                                    <Label 
                                        Text="{Binding cbrainBibleTOList.chapter}"
                                        Font="20" 
                                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                        TextColor="Black"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.Footer>
                    <Label/>
                </ListView.Footer>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

But no data is showing on the UI when running the project. Getting `Binding: 'book' property not found on 'System.Object[]', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'` message on output box. It is very difficult to implement grouping for a listview in xamarin forms. Can anyone help me to do this? I have uploaded a sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FfE_RvgZgTkSCmVrN8KSq3Y17odU7YUe).

Comment: Your sample seems contains the your personal url . I suggest that you should remove it and create a demo with static data .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT It is my personal URL, I will remove the sample after getting a solution. Can you help me?

Comment: I could not access it from remote .And I will test it with static source .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the latest [BindableLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts) of Xamarin.Forms version >=3.5 instead of using grouped Listview with less effort involved.

Update your **Model** class

```
public class CbrainBibleBooksHB
{
   public string book { get; set; }
   public List<CbrainBibleTOList> cbrainBibleTOList { get; set; }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ScrollView>
    <FlexLayout
        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}"
        Direction="Column"
        AlignContent="Start">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0"
                            Text="{Binding book}"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1"
                                    BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding cbrainBibleTOList}">
                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Label Text="{Binding chapter}">
                                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.TapCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=ParentContentPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Label>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </FlexLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Note: Here **ParentContentPage** is the x:Name of parent content page which is used to give reference for command.

**ViewModel:**

```
class BibleTestamentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand TapCommand { get; private set; }

    public BibleTestamentViewModel()
    {
        TapCommand = new Command(ChapterClickedClicked);
    }

    private void ChapterClickedClicked(object sender)
    {
        //check value inside sender
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I will try this. Did you work on my sample project, if yes can you please provide the working sample.

Comment: Can you share that sample?

Comment: I try to read the corresponding item data when tapping one chapter. Tried like below, but getting null value.

public void OpenChapter(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            var item = sender as CbrainBibleTOList;
            if(item != null)
            {
                //code execution not coming here
            }
        }

Comment: I need the entire CbrainBibleTOList values when select one chapter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200709/discussion-between-sreejith-sree-and-himanshu-dwivedi).

Answer (score 1):

I tested your demo with static data and there are some issues in your case .

Firstly **CbrainBibleBooksHB**  is a subclass of **ObservableCollection** ,so you don't need to set the property **cbrainBibleTOList**  any more

```
public class CbrainBibleBooksHB : ObservableCollection<CbrainBibleTOList>
{
   public string book { get; set; }
   public List<CbrainBibleTOList> cbrainBibleTOList { get; set; }
}
```

Secondly , you set the wrong binding path of the label .

```
<Label 
   Text="{Binding chapter}"
   ...
   />
```

Following is my code ,because of I could not accsess to your url so I used the static data.

#### in xaml

```
...
<Label 
   Text="{Binding chapter}"
   HeightRequest="30"
   Font="20" 
   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
   TextColor="Black"
   VerticalOptions="Center"/>
...
```

#### in viewmodel

```
namespace TestamentSample
{
    public class BibleTestamentViewModel 
    {
        

        public ObservableCollection<CbrainBibleBooksHB> AllItems
        {
            get;set;
        }

        public BibleTestamentViewModel()
        {

            
            var cbrainBibleBooksHB = new CbrainBibleBooksHB() {book = "group1",};

            cbrainBibleBooksHB.Add(new CbrainBibleTOList() { chapter = "1111" });
            cbrainBibleBooksHB.Add(new CbrainBibleTOList() { chapter = "2222" });
            cbrainBibleBooksHB.Add(new CbrainBibleTOList() { chapter = "3333" });
            cbrainBibleBooksHB.Add(new CbrainBibleTOList() { chapter = "4444" });
            cbrainBibleBooksHB.Add(new CbrainBibleTOList() { chapter = "5555" });


            var cbrainBibleBooksHB2 = new CbrainBibleBooksHB() { book = "group2", };

            cbrainBibleBooksHB2.Add(new CbrainBibleTOList() { chapter = "6666" });
            cbrainBibleBooksHB2.Add(new CbrainBibleTOList() { chapter = "7777" });
            cbrainBibleBooksHB2.Add(new CbrainBibleTOList() { chapter = "8888" });
            cbrainBibleBooksHB2.Add(new CbrainBibleTOList() { chapter = "9999" });
            cbrainBibleBooksHB2.Add(new CbrainBibleTOList() { chapter = "0000" });

            AllItems = new ObservableCollection<CbrainBibleBooksHB>() {
                cbrainBibleBooksHB,cbrainBibleBooksHB2
            };
        }
       
    }
}
```

```
public class CbrainBibleBooksHB : ObservableCollection<CbrainBibleTOList>
{
  public string book { get; set; }      
}
```

[image: Effect]

You should make sure that the object which you download from remote url has the same level with my demo .

Comment: You can download it and test https://github.com/luczha/TestamentSample.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way aswell

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Itens}" SeparatorColor="#010d47"  RowHeight="120" x:Name="lvEmpresaPending" SelectionMode="None">
                                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <ViewCell>
                                                    <StackLayout>
                                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                            <Label Text="Nome da Empresa:" FontAttributes="Bold" ></Label>
                                                            <Label Text="{Binding Main.Nome}"></Label>
                                                        </StackLayout>
                                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                            <Label Text="CNPJ da Empresa:" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                                                            <Label Text="{Binding Main.Cnpj}"></Label>
                                                        </StackLayout>
                                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                            <Label Text="Cargo: " FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                                                            <Label Text="{Binding Cargo}"></Label>
                                                        </StackLayout>
                                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                            <Label Text="Inicio" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                                                            <Label Text="{Binding DataInicio}"></Label>
                                                            <Label Text="Término" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                                                            <Label Text="{Binding DataFim}"></Label>

                                                        </StackLayout>

                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                </ViewCell>
                                            </DataTemplate>



public class ModelosPPP
    {
        public Empresa Main { get; set; }
        public string DataInicio { get; set; }
        public string DataFim { get; set; }
        public string Cargo { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }


 public class Empresa
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Cnpj { get; set; }
    }
```